# ng-repeat is Working perfectly with static json But fires exception with dynamic json data

Tags: html, angularjs, ajax, angular-routing

I have a ng-repeat put on a list to display in table.

the script html code is like this :

```
`<tr ng-repeat="user in users track by $index" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}">
                    <td>
                        {{user.FirstName}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{user.LastName}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{user.EmailId}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{user.ContactNumber}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>`
```

and in angular script the routing is defined as bellow:

```
var routingApp = angular.module('App', []);
routingApp.controller("MovieController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.edit = false;
$scope.error = false;
$scope.success = false;
//TO DO : Below portion to be replaced with ajax call to get list of movies from DB
var users = [
    { "UserId": 1, "FirstName": "user", "LastName": "1", "EmailId": "user1@gmail.com", "ContactNumber": 1234567890, "UserName": "User1", "Password": "Welcome@1" },
    { "UserId": 2, "FirstName": "user", "LastName": "2", "EmailId": "user2_1993@gmail.com", "ContactNumber": 7894612305, "UserName": "User2", "Password": "Welcome@2" },
    { "UserId": 3, "FirstName": "user", "LastName": "3", "EmailId": "user3@gmail.com", "ContactNumber": 1472583690, "UserName": "User3", "Password": "Welcome@3" },
    { "UserId": 4, "FirstName": "user", "LastName": "4", "EmailId": "user4@gmail.com", "ContactNumber": 7531598520, "UserName": "User4", "Password": "Welcome@4" },
    { "UserId": 5, "FirstName": "User", "LastName": "5", "EmailId": "user5@gmail.com", "ContactNumber": 4785961235, "UserName": "user5", "Password": "Welcome@5" }
];
console.log(users); //debugger;
    $scope.users = users;


}]);
```

This part is working absolutely fine.

but when i replace the static json data ie;

```
 var users = [
    { "UserId": 1, "FirstName": "user", "LastName": "1", "EmailId": "user1@gmail.com", "ContactNumber": 1234567890, "UserName": "User1", "Password": "Welcome@1" },
    { "UserId": 2, "FirstName": "user", "LastName": "2", "EmailId": "user2_1993@gmail.com", "ContactNumber": 7894612305, "UserName": "User2", "Password": "Welcome@2" },
    { "UserId": 3, "FirstName": "user", "LastName": "3", "EmailId": "user3@gmail.com", "ContactNumber": 1472583690, "UserName": "User3", "Password": "Welcome@3" },
    { "UserId": 4, "FirstName": "user", "LastName": "4", "EmailId": "user4@gmail.com", "ContactNumber": 7531598520, "UserName": "User4", "Password": "Welcome@4" },
    { "UserId": 5, "FirstName": "User", "LastName": "5", "EmailId": "user5@gmail.com", "ContactNumber": 4785961235, "UserName": "user5", "Password": "Welcome@5" }
];
```

with

```
$http.get("http://localhost:82/api/User/GetAllUsers")
.then(function (response) {
    dt = JSON.stringify(response.data);
    $scope.users = dt;
    //console.log(dt);
    //console.log(JSON.parse(dt));
})
```

it will through this exception :

```
`[ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: user in users, Duplicate key: string:", Duplicate value`
```

But the output of the api is exactly same as static json, in fact i have copied json from api output itself.

Even i have tried removing  `track by $index` but No luck.
are there any solutions to this issue?

Comment: Try this  `.then(function (response) {
       $scope.users = response.data;
    })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//dont stringify your api response and try this
$scope.users = response.data;

//html
<tr ng-repeat="user in users track by user.UserId" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `JSON.parse` instead of `JSON.stringify`, you're trying to loop over a string (`JSON.stringify` returns a string). Anyway, if the data is sent back in JSON format just assign the data.

Answer (score 1):

try with below code

```
 $http.get("http://localhost:82/api/User/GetAllUsers")
.then(function (response) {
dt = JSON.stringify(response.data);
$scope.users = response.data;

})
```

Answer (score 1):

try this without stringifying the response and itrate through users.

```
$http.get("http://localhost:82/api/User/GetAllUsers")
.then(function (response) {

$scope.users = response.data;

})
```